# What the general purpose when using cin.clear?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am a **beginner** to c++, and I just can't wrap my head around whats cin.ignore & cin.clear, they make absolutely no sense to me. When you explain this to me, please be **very descriptive**

Answer (score 1):

In C++ input processing, `cin.fail()` would return true if the last `cin` command failed.

Usually, `cin.fail()` would return true in the following cases:

1. anytime you reach the `EOF` and try to read anything, `cin.fail()` would return true.
2. if you try to read an integer and it receives something that cannot be converted to an integer.

When `cin.fail()` return true and error occurs, the input buffer of `cin` is placed in an "error state". The state would block the further input processing.

Therefore, you have to use `cin.clear()`. It would overwrite the current value of the stream internal error flag => All bits are replaced by those in state, if state is good bit all error flags are cleared.

---

For `cin.ignore`, first it would accesses the input sequence by first constructing a `sentry` object. After that, it extracts characters from its associated stream buffer object as if calling its member functions `sbumpc` or `sgetc`, and finally destroys the sentry object before returning.

Therefore, It commonly used to perform extracting and discarding characters. A classical cases of `cin.ignore` is that when you're using `getline()` after `cin`, it would leaves a newline in your buffer until you switch function. That why you **MUST** flush the newline out of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`std::cin.ignore()` can be called three different ways:

No arguments: A single character is taken from the input buffer and discarded:

```
std::cin.ignore(); //discard 1 character
```

One argument: The number of characters specified are taken from the input buffer and discarded:

```
std::cin.ignore(33); //discard 33 characters
```

Two arguments: discard the number of characters specified, or discard characters up to and including the specified delimiter (whichever comes first):

```
std::cin.ignore(26, '\n'); //ignore 26 characters or to a newline, whichever comes first
```

source: http://www.augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/tutorial/iotips.html

Comment: The recommended ignore is `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`, but when using this in the general sense you have to be a bit careful. It's potentially waiting for a few kaijuzillion characters if it doesn't find a line feed and this is pretty much a waste of everybody's time.

Comment: ty for the tip and for this word "kaijuzillion" i love it.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` is more than just a large number. It's a special case for `ignore()` that disables counting so it consumes all characters up to and including the delimiter.